# Validation for file upload extension error using ext_in[] in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I'm using flutter to upload files to a Php codeigniter 4 server. My problem is when I add validation for the uploaded file type. It always return `file does not have a valid file extension`.

Upload.php

```
$rules = [
 'file' => 'uploaded[file]|max_size[file, 4096]|ext_in[file,jpg,jpeg,png,doc,docx,pdf]'
];
```

Here is the debug of $_FILES that I recieved.

```
{"file":{"name":"file_test.jpg","type":"application\/octet-stream","tmp_name":"C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php623C.tmp","error":0,"size":169233}}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add ".tmp" extension in your ext_in? Because your file is not actually a .jpg when importing it through $_FILES variable but a .tmp.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the form field

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is fine, you should add another attribute to your form, but it works for only HTML forms, but not in flutter context.

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71425356/7742526), it may help for you.

The idea is right, because if you omit the *enctype="multipart/form-data"*
attribute the CodeIgniter will not get the file and the **ext_in** validation will fail. You can check the [source code here](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/v4.4.3/system/Validation/FileRules.php#L200C34-L200C34). If you set the attribute, CodeIgniter will get the file and it will works fine.