# How to send multipart file with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, multipartform-data, dio

I would like to send a picture as a multipart file to the server.

First I tried to use **http.post** :

```
var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('url.php'),
      headers:{ "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" } ,
      body: {
        "fichier": base64img
      }
    );
```

I got this error :

> Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type
> "multipart/form-data".

Looking at the answers of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125191/how-to-upload-images-and-file-to-a-server-in-flutter) I tried to use the **dio package** :

```
var dio = Dio();
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'fichier': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'upload')
    });
    var response = await dio.post(
      'url.php', 
      data: formData
    );
```

I got this error :

> Error: Unsupported operation: MultipartFile is only supported where
> dart:io is available.

An issue as already been open [here](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1067).

Finally, I try to use **MultipartRequest** from the **http package** :

```
var url = Uri.parse('url.php');
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
    request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        "fichier", 
        filePath
      )
    );
    request.send().then((response) => print(response));
```

Got the same exact same error than with the dio package.

If anyone as a solution, I would gladly take it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use http package and get image using `fromBytes` intead `fromPath`:

```
final uri = Uri.parse('https://myendpoint.com');
var request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
final httpImage = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('files.myimage', bytes,
    contentType: MediaType.parse(mimeType), filename: 'myImage.png');
request.files.add(httpImage);
final response = await request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, out of curiosity what does this part do :  contentType: MediaType.parse(mimeType) and where it is defined ? Btw, tried without this part and works well.

Comment: It is just a metadata from any file. You dont need it.

Comment: Where do you add the name of the field in this method? In context of the question, `fichier` is what I am referring to

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567634/flutter-await-sometimes-not-working-async-ontap after upload i need return response body in Future<String>

Comment: @RubensMelo getting error if i recall this after refreshing the token on token expire.ie, same request can't send twice.Any solution??