# flutter await sometimes not working async onTap()

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am using imagePicker and I want to upload image after select and show it in its image box and store upload respons as string in local storage and "static String AddNewProductByUser.pic5", local storage storing is not important

```
InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    AddNewProductByUser.pic5 = await _getImageAndUpload(ImageSource.gallery);
                    print('(success)AddNewProductByUser.pic5>>>>${AddNewProductByUser.pic5}');
                    localStorage ?? await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    localStorage?.setString("product_pic5", AddNewProductByUser.pic5);
                    _selectedImageFileObj = null;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
```

And _getImageAndUpload() with awiat

```
XFile? _selectedImageFileObj;
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
SharedPreferences? localStorage;

Future<String> _getImageAndUpload(ImageSource media) async {
    _selectedImageFileObj = await picker.pickImage(source: media);
    return await JJ.fileUpload(File(_selectedImageFileObj!.path));
 }
```

but some times it work truly like this :

> ```
> I/flutter (18058): (upload response code)200 (0)
> I/flutter (18058): (upload result)p7928552424.jpg  (1)
> I/flutter (18058): (success)AddNewProductByUser.pic5>>>>p7928552424.jpg (2)
> ```

but sometimes (50% of total try times) it is wrong like this:

> ```
> I/flutter (18058): (upload response code)200     (0)
> I/flutter (18058): (success) AddNewProductByUser.pic5>>>>    (2)
> I/flutter (18058): (upload result) p7928552424.jpg     (1)
> ```

JJ.fileUpload is like this :

```
static Future<String> fileUpload(File imageFile) async {
try {
  String result = '';
  var stream = http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
  stream.cast();
  var length = await imageFile.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse("${JJ.server}UploadServlet");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
      filename: basename(imageFile.path));
  //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));
  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  final response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
      result = value;
    });
    return result;
  }
  jjToast('err 78');
  return '';
} catch (e) {
  jjToast('err 81');
  return '';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In final step of fileUpload() use await for like this:

```
  final contents = StringBuffer(); 
  await for (var data in response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
      contents.write(data);
      return contents.toString();
  }
```